# Is the save method required to be called on Order object updates?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After seeing several of @LoicTheAztec answers that included a call to the WC Order object method `save()`, I started adding them to my code when I would do things like:

```
function update_next_payment_date($subscription, $old_status, $new_status) {
    $new_date = array(
       'next_payment' => new DateTime('August 1, 2021');
    );
 
    $subscription->update_dates($new_date);

    $subscription->save();
}
```

I ran into a problem where I was using an order status updated hook, but the `save()` method caused an infinite recursive loop because `save()` also calls `status_transition` which triggered the hook again.

I seem to be able to update the dates without the call to the `save` method, so is it required? If not, what is it for?

Comment: Which action do you use to call `update_next_payment_date()`?

Comment: In this case it was `woocommerce_subscription_status_updated` which is, I believe, an extension of `woocommerce_order_status_changed`.

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it is not clear which action you are using to call your hook. Let us assume it is `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hooked by the following line:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'update_next_payment_date', 10, 3 );
```

Then, to prevent the infinite loop, you have to remove your action at the beginning of the callback and restore it at the end:

```
function update_next_payment_date( $subscription, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'update_next_payment_date', 10 );

    $new_date = array(
        'next_payment' => new DateTime( 'August 1, 2021' )
    );

    $subscription->update_dates( $new_date );

    $subscription->save();

    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'update_next_payment_date', 10, 3 );
}
```

You have to use in the `remove_action` the same priority (10), as specified in `add_action`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that this would help prevent the infinite loop, but I don't understand the implications or mechanisms of `remove_action()`. Also, `update_dates()` works without `save()` being present, so to my original question: when is the `save()` method actually necessary or useful?

Comment: I haven't look at the WooCommerce code now, but as far as I remember update is not enough, and you have to use save.

Comment: `update_dates()` by itself seems to persist the data just fine, that's what confused me.

Comment: update_dates saves dates in the object `WC_Subscription` which is an extension of standard WooCommerce `WC_Order`. All objects in WC must use save() to write changes to the database. Look at the code of the Subscription plugin, for instance, in the `\WCS_Meta_Box_Schedule::save` function. Here, the same sequence is used: first, `update_dates()`, then `save()`. So you definitely have to use `save()`.

Comment: `remove_action` / `add_action` is a standard mechanism in WordPress, it has no implications.

Comment: I'm very curious about why the data is persisting just fine without the use of `save()` in our case, then. 

By the way, I missed the second part where you re-added the action - that's why I was asking about implications of removing it. Thanks!